# Get error when deserialize JSON object to DataTable

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net, json-deserialization

My code is:

```cs
DataTable dsAcknowledgement = new DataTable();               
int Count = 1;

dsAcknowledgement = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(Convert.ToString(Input));
foreach (DataRow dr in dsAcknowledgement.Rows)
{
    string encrypteddata = Convert.ToString(dr["url"]);
    string DecrypteUrl = SbntAPICrypto.Decrypt(Encrypt_AES256_Key, Encrypt_AES256_iv,         encrypteddata);
    Count++;
}

Input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsAcknowledgement);
return ShipmateWebService(Input);
```

I get the following error:

> "Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1."

How to convert this JSON object to DataTable?

```
{
  "ServiceName": "Fileabcdssss",
  "origin": "abc",
  "Data": [
    {
      "status": 200,
      "statusMessage": "success",
      "url": "FILE_URL"
    },
    {
      "status": 200,
      "statusMessage": "success",
      "url": "FILE1_URL"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is an object but not an array. And deserialize to `DataTable` requires a JSON array.

Assume that you are trying to extract the `Data` array from the JSON object, you should extract as below:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

dsAcknowledgement = JObject.Parse(Convert.ToString(Input))
            .SelectToken("Data")
            .ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TtOzWS)